# Run exe outside of gradle scope

Tags: gradle

I am trying to kick of an exe (mongodb) from gradle, but need that exe to run outside of gradle scope so that the gradle task is not blocked for ever.

```
task startMongo(type: Exec) {
    executable "$buildDir/mongo/mongod.exe"
    args "--dbpath=$buildDir/mongo/data/db"
}
```

Mongodb starts fine, but the task is blocked as the mongo server waits for connections.

```
2014-12-10T14:30:33.018-0700 [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25295945/run-a-background-job-from-gradle

Answer (score 0):

Robert - thank you. I wrote a custom gradle task and started the exe in background.

```
class MyTask extends DefaultTask {   
    @TaskAction
    void startProcess() {     
        ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder()
        processBuilder.command('exe-path', 'arg')
        processBuilder.start()   
    }
```