# Gradle ExecTask and Windows start

Tags: visual-studio, gradle, cmd

This question requires an understanding of both the Window's start command's behavior and a custom gradle ExecTask's handling of it.

### Question

Why does start, with an application as a parameter, wait for the application to exit, only when being executed within a gradle ExecTask?

### Explanation

From the command line, this works as expected (starts the application and returns, without waiting for the application to exit):

```
cmd /c myBuildEnvironment.cmd && start "some title for start" devenv.exe my.sln
```

Pretty simple, it calls a windows batch script to setup the environment and then launches `my.sln` in Visual Studio.  Works just fine, not waiting for Visual Studio to be closed.  And, this is what my gradle task is meant to achieve.

The same works "somewhat", using the following gradle ExecTask with start:

```
/**
 * I know that the executable + args is replaced by commandLine.  They're
 * just there for readability.
 */
task openVsSolution(type: Exec, dependsOn: setupVsSln) {
    description 'Opens the VS solution, in the appropriate version of Visual Studio.'

    executable 'start'
    environment = taskEnv
    workingDir '../../src/solution'
    args = [vsDevEnv, 'my.sln']
    commandLine winCmdPrefix + executable + args
}
```

Gradle happily reports `Build Successful`, while Visual Studio remains open.

However, I say "somewhat" because `start` will actually ignore the `executable` argument and open `my.sln` with the default application for it, `Microsoft Visual Studio Version Selector`.  So, after some research, I found that `start` assumes that the first parameter is the window title, then application, and lastly, the application arguments.  So, I tried this:

```
task openVsSolution(type: Exec, dependsOn: setupVsSln) {
    executable 'start'
    environment = taskEnv
    workingDir '../../src/solution'
    args = ['some title for start', vsDevEnv, 'my.sln']
    commandLine winCmdPrefix + executable + args
}
```

Everything works, `start` used the correct version of Visual Studio's `devenv.exe`, which varies based on the `VC PlatformToolset`, but...gradle sits in the background waiting for Visual Studio to close.

***Why?  How can I achieve all of the desired behavior?***

### Update

This might be an environmental problem.  Apparently, on one dev's machine, the original gradle start task does stay open, as well.  So, any invocation of start through gradle waits for it to complete, in a certain environment.  The plot thickens...

Answer (score 0):

Gradle is waiting for start to return is my guess, see this post - [Run a background job from Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25295945/run-a-background-job-from-gradle).  Read also the comment after the answer, this is started from Java so if there is equivalent of & (run in background) for windows, it wouldn't work.

You can also try and wrapping it in a bat file, execute what you want in the bat file in the background then return right away so that gradle would be happy.

Hope this helps.

Comment: As I said in the post, the start command was working before, within gradle.  It was only after I added more arguments to the start command that gradle now seems to wait for it to return.  However, the new start command run directly from the command line, as in the first command shown, does not wait.  So, what is that command doing differently that now causes gradle to wait?  I didn't use the start /wait command.